Selenium WebDriver inside of Blazor Server app
I have a desktop app that uses webdriver to:

open a browser
navigate to a website
log in
navigate to a form
fill out the top part of the form
leave the window up for the user to fill out the bottom of the form and submit.

I am wanting to make a web version of the app using blazor, and I am wondering if there is a way to have this functionality in it, except step 1 would be replace with "open a new tab or window".
I tried doing it the same way as on the desktop app, but of course it opens the browser on the server, not the users machine since blazor is running server side, not client side.
I've run across mentions of webdriver JS, but I'm not sure if it's a javascript version of webdriver, or if it's something completely different.
It doesn't have to be webdriver, but is there any way to get something similar to work?

the webdrivers are executables that would have to run on the server... you might do something like takescreenshots or stream video of a server's run.  The browser has a sandbox that separates the internet from local.... there's another sandbox inside of that for web assembly.  (blazor can be run client-side)  It's worth noting that Selenium began as a browser extension/plugin that could record and playback scripts, so that is an option.  (I think that's branched over to SeleniumIDE?)

another option would be a ClickOnce app, but it's not going to actually run in the browser... it would download/launch a desktop app.

@browsermator the current app is distributed through ClickOnce, and yeah I'm hoping for a completely machine independent solution. Mobile phone, tablet, laptop, mac, whatever, just be able to make it run.

if running as a desktop app you can add all the drivers as resources, or rely (at least partly) on the built-in driver manager to download them..)  The tricky part will be mobile as that's usually something like Appium.  There is a HTMLUnit github project for droid, though:  https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android  None of those would run in the browser... and controlling existing session would require that the browser is launched in dev-mode and that you have the port and/or sessionID from that launch.

I just noticed an option under Solution Explorer: Add->Client side library... and I'm wondering what that means? Can I add a library that downloads to the clients machine and runs code locally? If so that could solve my problem

the drivers are executables.  You can extract them at run-time if you add them as resources.  I suppose you can add as a library if you built from source code as library?  Never tried that... not sure that helps you with the sandbox issue though.
